# Why does pyinstaller create a huge exe file when using it with pdfminer modules in Python 3.6?

Tags: pyinstaller, pdfminer

I try to create an exe file with pyinstaller (in Python 3.6) from a script that is using pdfminer modules but the created exe file is huge, **around 240 MB**. In contrast, when using pyinstaller in Python 2.7 with a similar script the created exe file is only around 10 MB.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

I create the exe file with the following command: *pyinstaller.exe --onefile {filename/path}*

My code:

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage

...

def convert_pdf_to_txt(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = io.StringIO()
    #codec = 'windows-1250'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    # reply = s.get(path, stream=True, verify= False)
    # fp = StringIO()
    # fp.write(reply.content)
    # fp.seek(0)
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos = set()

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password, caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = retstr.getvalue()

    fp.close()
    device.close()
    retstr.close()
    return text

...
```

Comment: i would suggest to disable onefile option to investigate if there is a residual output files bundled as part of output. There could be templates, etc that files not being used as part of your output. You may need to exclusively remove those from your output with pyinstaller spec file. pyinstaller bundles your source as 12mb when i tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following solution:

1. Created a virtual environment
2. Via pip installed only the packages needed (i.e. pdfminer and pyinstaller).

The result in now an exe file that is only 7.8 MB.